# Detect multiple empty lines in contenteditable DIV

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this editable DIV:

```
<div contenteditable>
    First line
    Second line

    Third line    



    Fourth line
</div>
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Mpvyk/1/

Notice the 3 empty lines between "Third line" and "Fourth line". I would like to replace those 3 empty lines with a single empty line.

So, inside the DIV, for all occurrences of this:

```
'\n' (zero or more spaces or tabs) '\n' (zero or more spaces or tabs) '\n' etc.
```

replace it with one single empty line:

```
`\n\n`
```

What I have so far:

```
var text = div.textContent;

text.replace(/ ??? /gm, '\n\n');

div.textContent = text;
```

As you can see, I don't know how to write the regular expression which would select those occurrences of multiple empty lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think the regexp you're after is `/\n\s+\n/`: a newline, any amount of space-like characters and another newline.

However you'd need to save the result, too: `text = text.replace(...)`.

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0],
    text = div.textContent;

 text = text.replace(/\n\s+\n/gm, '\n\n');

div.textContent = text;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mpvyk/2/

Comment: Btw is it just me or is jsfiddle extremely slow today?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I'm experiencing that as well; sometimes it isn't quite responding lately.

Comment: Btw the `m` multiline flag is for some reason [not required](http://jsfiddle.net/Mpvyk/6/) here... which is strange since we do match over multiple ines...

Comment: @Šime Vidas: In fact it has not much to do with matching over multiple lines here, only just the behaviour of `^` and `$` not being the beginning/ending of a line but rather of the complete string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp

Comment: Note that the OP said *zero* or more spaces between newlines. This will require at least one space. Also, it may not catch overlapping matches, such as `\n\s\n\s\n`.

Comment: @Justin Morgan: But in case of nothing in between, i.e. `\n\n`, there is no point in replacing. And `"\n  \n    \n".replace(/\n\s+\n/gm, '\n\n');` returns correctly for me, or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: My understanding was that `\n\n\n...` (any more than 2 `\n`) should still be shrunk down to `\n\n`, regardless of whether there are spaces in between. I wasn't sure about JS's handling of overlapping matches, but it looks like that's not an issue if it worked for you.

Comment: @Justin Morgan: `"\n\n\n".replace(/\n\s+\n/gm, '\n\n') === "\n\n"`. Not sure if this works for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something fairly simple:

```
text.replace(/\n{3,}/gm, '\n\n');
```

Or, to ignore whitespace between the lines (I think this is the one you want):

```
text.replace(/(\n\s*){3,}/gm, '\n\n');
```